# Django - how to see ALL column results of a join using .select_related()?

Tags: django

I am having difficulty seeing the foreign table's field from a resulting join using select_related(). Any idea what my issue is here?

Define models

```
class Magazine(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True, primary_key=True)
    founded = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True, primary_key=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Issue(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(Magazine, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column="name")
    week = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.week
```

Register

```
from mainsite.models import Magazine, Issue
admin.site.register(Magazine)
admin.site.register(Issue)
```

Migrate

```
python ../manage.py makemigrations
python ../manage.py migrate
```

Loading data

```
import os
import sys
import django
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.getcwd()))
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'mags.settings') #configures the settings for the project. Need to do this before manipulating models
django.setup()
from mainsite.models import Magazine, Issue

magazineNames = ['journal science', 'naughty mag', 'funny cartoons', 'comic fans', 'lawncare', 'NEVERISSUED']
magazineFounded = ['1901', '1995', '2005', '2011', '1993', '1900']
Magazine.objects.bulk_create([Magazine(name=i, founded=j) for i,j in zip(magazineNames, magazineFounded)])

issueNames = ['journal science', 'journal science', 'naughty mag', 'funny cartoons', 'comic fans', 'lawncare', 'lawncare']
issueWeeks = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7']
Issue.objects.bulk_create([Issue(name=Magazine(name=i), week=j) for i,j in zip(issueNames, issueWeeks)])

#QUERY
Issue.objects.select_related("name").values_list()
```

> <QuerySet [(1, 'journal science', '1'), (2, 'journal science', '2'), (3, 'naughty mag', '3'), (4, 'funny cartoons', '4'), (5, 'comic fans', '5'), (6, 'lawncare', '6'), (7, 'lawncare', '7')]>

Comment: A `.select_related(..)` has *no* impact on a `.values_list(..)`. You should also *not* use a `.values_list`/`.values` to retrieve data: https://www.django-antipatterns.com/antipattern/over-use-of-values.html

Comment: Then how do otherwise you see the result?

Answer (score 0):

You specify the columns you want to include:

```
Issue.objects.select_related("name").values_list('week', 'name__name')
```

Comment: You don't need to use `.select_related(..)`, just specifying `name__name` is enough.

Comment: True, it's only needed when he need to optimize the query execution time, it wasn't clear why he did use it

Comment: no,this will not make any difference for the query (and hence the query executation time). `.select_related` only has effect if you fetch *model objects*, not tuples or dictionaries with `.values(..)` or `.values_list(..)`.

Comment: I need the select_relate() in order to execute an inner join. I want to perform an inner join and then see all fields across both tables.